# Querying JSON data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, query

I am struggling to extract data from a table, which was partially inserted from a JSON file. The table has two fields (name nvarchar(50) and details nvarchar(max). The values of the fields are:

```
name      details
user01    [{"data": ["SQL Server", "DBA"], "id": 123456}, {"data": ["Profiler", "Tuning"], "recno": 123123}]
user02    [{"data": [], "recno": 121212}, {"data": ["MySQL"], "recno": 112233}]
```

I need to have this data in three columns (name, id and data) in a new table.

```
name,   id,     data
user01  123456  SQL Server, DBA 
user01  123123  Profiler, Tuning
user02  112233  MySQL
```

Would you know how to do it?

Comment: Is this your actual JSON data? The JSON value `[MySQL]` is invalid; it should be `["MySQL"]`.

Comment: True. I corrected this

Comment: Please, tag your SQL Server version.

Comment: Is it `{"date": ["Profiler", "Tuning"]` or `{"data": ["Profiler", "Tuning"]` with a `a`

Comment: Yes, data updated

Answer (score 1):

I've set up a table with your sample data with a couple of corrections:

- changed "date" to "data" (for consistency with other JSON entries)
- changed "recno" to "id" (for consistency with desired output and across JSON entries

Let me know if those corrections were invalid.  It's possible to workaround / coalesce the values of "recno" and "id" if they are both used interchangeably in the real data.

```
USE [tempdb];
GO

CREATE TABLE #JsonStuff
(
    [name] varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    details nvarchar(max) NOT NULL
);
GO

INSERT INTO #JsonStuff
    ([name], details)
VALUES
    ('user01', N'[{"data": ["SQL Server", "DBA"], "id": 123456}, {"data": ["Profiler", "Tuning"], "id": 123123}]'),
    ('user02', N'[{"data": [], "id": 121212}, {"data": ["MySQL"], "id": 112233}]');
```

You can get close to your desired results with this query:

```
SELECT 
    [name], 
    main.id, 
    main.[data]
FROM #JsonStuff js
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (js.details)
WITH
(
    id int '$.id',
    [data] nvarchar(max) AS JSON
) AS main
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1/0 
    FROM OPENJSON (main.[data])
);
```

The query selects each `[name]` from the table.

The `OPENJSON` function is used to access the structured data inside the documents.

It then uses `CROSS APPLY` over the JSON data in order to get a row per array entry in the JSON document.

Finally, the `WHERE EXISTS` clause is used to eliminate rows where the "data" array in the JSON document is empty.  Results look like this:

[image: screenshot of query results]

To get rid of the square braces and double quotes, one would need to use `OPENJSON` again on the `data` element to get a row per inner array element, and then do normal string concatenation after that.  Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    [name], 
    main.id, 
    STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT ',' + [sublist].[value]
            FROM OPENJSON(main.[data]) AS sublist 
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 1, 1, ''
    ) AS [data]
FROM #JsonStuff js
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (js.details)
WITH
(
    id int '$.id',
    [data] nvarchar(max) AS JSON
) AS main
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1/0 
    FROM OPENJSON (main.[data])
);
```

Results look like this:

[image: screenshot of results with square braces and double quotes removed]

I should note that this is probably not great for performance (`OPENJSON` gets called a bunch of times, and the string concatenation is just the first one I came across).

Comment: Awesome! That works perfectly Josh. Thanks a mil

Comment: @xac Glad I could help!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what the tables and their contents look at the moment,
but as far as I understand from your question, I would recommend you shoud create a new column and then do something like

```
update tablename
set your_new_column = (select COALESCE (column1_info, column2_info) from tablename where id = your_rows_id)
```

where column1_info and column2_info is the information you would like extract from that column

see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15